# horizontally shift starting point for stem() in MatLab

Tags: matlab, plot

I have a sequence with data and an offset. I'm asked to plot a stem() graph of the data, starting at the offset. I have figured out the data part (the easy part) and how to change the window to include the offset, but when I plot the graph, it shows the offset with a value of zero and zeros until 1 where the sequence.data will start and plot points.

```
methods
    function s = sequence(data, offset)
        s.data = data;
        s.offset = offset;
    end
function stem(x)
        % STEM Display a Matlab sequence, x, using a stem plot.
        stem(x.offset,x.data);
        axis([x.offset x.offset+length(x.data) 'auto' 'auto']);

    end
```

I need to figure out how to "move" my x.data to my x.offset and start stem plotting there.

Comment: I don't fully understand your question, but maybe use `NaN`s instead of zeros? `NaN`s don't get plotted

Comment: All of the stem() examples that I've seen start the plot at 0, but I need my plot to start at the offset of the sequence. For example, if my sequence is x = sequence([1 2 3 4 5], -3) then my stem plot would be [-3,1][-2,2][-1,3][0,4][1,5]. So far, I can't get my plot to start at -3. It'll currently be [-3,0][-2,0][-1,0][0,0][1,1][2,2][3,3][4,4][5,5].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why you simply can't add an `x` offset while keeping the `y` data the same?

For instance, given your example in your comments above:

```
x = 0:4;
y = 1:5;
```

This is what the original graph looks like, as well as shifting the graph to the left by 3 (`-3`):

```
stem(x,y,'b');
hold on;
stem(x-3,y,'r');
```

This is what I get:

[image]

The blue data is the original, while the red is the shifted instance to the left by 3.  As you can see, the `y` data is the same, but the `x` points move to the left by 3.  What your code is actually doing is that it **does not** shift the actual data.  You are only changing the **display** range of your `stem` plot.  As such, you should really be doing this:

```
methods
    function s = sequence(data, offset)
        s.data = data;
        s.offset = offset;
    end
    function stem(x)
        % STEM Display a Matlab sequence, x, using a stem plot.
        %// First define sequence from [0,N-1]
        vals = 0:numel(x.data)-1;
        %// Now use the above and manually shift the x coordinate
        stem(vals+x.offset,x.data);
    end
```

I'm going to assume that your data on the `x`-axis starts counting at `0`, and so we will declare a sequence from `0` up to `N-1` where `N` is the total number of elements that you have.  Once we declare this sequence, when it's time to draw the `stem` plot, we simply add an offset to this sequence and use this as the `x` data.  The `y` data should stay the same.

However, I would argue that creating a custom class for implementing this addition to `stem` is less readable than what I originally did above.  If this is a requirement for whatever you're developing, then certainly go ahead and do it this way, but I don't really think it's necessary.

Comment: My error came from not understanding the stem in the first place. You've definitely clarified how stem(X,Y) works. I wasn't thinking about it in the right way. I was, instead, thinking of X and Y as two sequences for some reason. Not sure why. Thank you.

Comment: @Mikael_SFSU - Ahhhh ok that makes sense :)  Well yes, `X` and `Y` are definitely two separate sequences.  Just make sure they're the same length.  It works by plotting stems at each corresponding `(x,y)` pair.  If you want to shift the data to the left by 3, simply subtract all `x` values by 3 while keeping the `y` data the same!  BTW, I didn't mean to sound hostile at the end of the post.  I'm re-reading the post now and it definitely sounds like I'm a bit p!$$ed off. I'm certainly not feeling that way. I was just curious as to why you're trying to make a new class when it's not needed.